# Compare two Count() values sql

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

I have a table called "Takes" that has the following information. Takes(stud_id, class_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)

I wanted to find the id's of the students who took more classes in 2009 than in 2010 (in terms of number of classes.
I have used the following code to extract the 2009 students total number of classes but not sure how to do the comparison

```
select stud_id, count(class_id) from Takes where year = 2009 group by stud_id;
```

Comment: Note that `year` is an ANSI SQL reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words), so it might need to be delimited as `"year"`, depending on the dbms your using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside an aggregation function) and a `HAVING` clause:

```
select
  stud_id,
  count(case when year = 2009 then 1 end) as classes_in_2009,
  count(case when year = 2010 then 1 end) as classes_in_2010
from takes 
group by stud_id
having count(case when year = 2009 then 1 end) >
       count(case when year = 2010 then 1 end);
```

Comment: I'd add `where year in (2009, 2010)`, will probably improve performance.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the most efficient query, but u can try this:

```
SELECT aa.Stud_id
FROM (  SELECT Stud_id, Year, COUNT(Class_id) Class_id
        FROM Takes
    GROUP BY Stud_id, Year) aa
    WHERE aa.Year = 2009
    AND aa.Class_id > (SELECT bb.Class_id
                        FROM (  SELECT Stud_id, Year, COUNT(Class_id) Class_id
                                  FROM Takes
                              GROUP BY Stud_id, Year) bb
                       WHERE aa.Stud_id = bb.Stud_id AND bb.Year = 2010);
```

This gets more effient by applying the `WHERE` clause right away and using `HAVING` for the comparision of the counts:

```
SELECT aa.Stud_id
FROM Takes aa
WHERE aa.Year = 2009
GROUP BY aa.Stud_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Takes bb
  WHERE bb.Stud_id = aa.Stud_id
  AND bb.Year = 2010
);
```

Comment: You are right, your query can be written more efficiently. I've done this for you and updated your answer with that query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks, very well written.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on dbms, a 2009 left join 2010 might speed things up:

```
select t2009.stud_id, t2009.cnt, t2010.cnt
from
 (select stud_id, count(*) as cnt
  from takes
  where year = 2009
  group by stud_id) t2009
LEFT JOIN
 (select stud_id, count(*) as cnt
  from takes
  where year = 2010
  group by stud_id) t2010
ON t2009.stud_id = t2010.stud_id AND t2009.cnt > t2010.cnt
```

(Assuming the year column is indexed.)